# How to hide html code in textarea tag when I use php to call data?

Tags: php, html

The following is my code:

```
<?php

$br = 
"AAA<br>
BBB<br>
CCC<br>";

echo $br;
?>
<textarea><?php echo $br; ?></textarea>
```

output:
[image]

You can see the html code(br) in the textarea tag.
 I want to hide the html code in textarea tag, any idea how to do it ? thx
I try to use htmlspecialchars_decode(), but not successful.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect candidate for [`strip_tags()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
<textarea><?php echo strip_tags($br); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Sir...! He wants the same formatting. but `strip_tags()` removes `<br />` tag then this become normal text...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma it does just that.

Comment: someone is commenting here and then removing those comments, why?

Comment: It works!!!!! Thank you very much!!! Thank you for very help!! Have a nice day!!!

Comment: @francoleung side note: `strip_tags()` can almost omit certain/specific tags. Go through the manual for some examples.